# VS Code - Go debug error - Could not launch process: fork/exec - Access Denied

Tags: go, debugging, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-debugging, delve

I have done a fresh installation of VS code and trying to debug a go Code. I am able to run the "go run main.go" command and getting the correct result. However, I am getting the below error while trying to debug the code. [image: Error Message]

I am not able to find any solution to this problem and The launch configuration looks like.

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "auto",
            "program": "main.go"
            
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I assume you need to check authorizations for the folder mentioned in the error message. VS debug first compliles _debug_bin.exe binary file, then tries to execute it and fails. You may also try to run VSCode as administrator and see if that helps.

Comment: I have tried VSCode as administrator but I was getting the same error.

Comment: Do you run Debug with custom launch.json? If so, make sure that you have `"mode": "auto"` or `"mode": "debug"` parameter set (not `"mode": "test"`)

Comment: @vtm11 I am getting the same error for "mode": "auto" or "mode": "debug" . I have added my Launch configuration in the question.

Comment: You may try to run `dlv debug main.go` from command line (navigate to your folder before running the command). If you get the same error - something is wrong with the Go debugger. It not - the trouble is with VSCode

Comment: You may also want to check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64382370/access-denied-when-launching-vscode-go-code-both-running-without-debugging-and-w).

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue. I solved by changing the go program location; it was previously in my Google Drive folder which has some privileges that VSCode couldn't run on it.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the error when I  was on a different code file which belonged to different go package. When I switched to main.go and tried to run the program the error vanished. I am on windows 11 btw.